# How to change the cursor to a custom image when clicking on an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i want to use javascript to change the cursor to a custom image by changing the cursor proprety of the whole page. and the console on chrome gives me this error:

```
projetFinalPage1.html:626 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at changeCursorGun (projetFinalPage1.html:626)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (projetFinalPage1.html:548)
changeCursorGun @ projetFinalPage1.html:626
onclick @ projetFinalPage1.html:548
```

heres my code

```js
function changeCursorGun(){
  document.getElementById("pageCombatAlien").style.cursor = "url('images/gunCursor')";
 }
```

```css
#pageCombatAlien{
 display: none;
 cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageCombatAlien">
   <div id="backgroundCombatAlien">
    <div id="texteCombatAlien">
    La voici la fameuse créature que mon détecteur a capté ! Je ne peux pas m'enfuir, car elle me rattarpera.
    </div>
    <input type="image" src="images/chest.png" onclick="changeCursorGun()" id="chest">
    <div id="healthBorder">
     <div id="health"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="healthLoss()" id="boiteClickAlien">
   </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You don't have an Element with an id of "PageCombatAlien"

Answer (score 1):

The error says the ElementById you are looking is null, so probably don't exist, show your full html and make sure PageCombatAlien is existing.

But you can do this with only css, like this

Run Code Snippet to see the efect

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>

<style>
.test {
  background:gray;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif), auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: heres my html for that section of my website :                    <div id="pageCombatAlien">
   <div id="backgroundCombatAlien">
    <div id="texteCombatAlien">
    La voici la fameuse créature que mon détecteur a capté ! Je ne peux pas m'enfuir, car elle me rattarpera.
    </div>
    <input type="image" src="images/chest.png" onclick="changeCursorGun()" id="chest">
    <div id="healthBorder">
     <div id="health"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="healthLoss()" id="boiteClickAlien">
   </div>

  </div>

Comment: Check my edit this is a much simpler way to accomplish what you want to do

Comment: My problem is that i only want the cursor to be that image when i click on the other div and stay changed when you move the mouse

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the `PageCombatAlien` element doesn't exist. From your updated question, this is because the capitalization is wrong. You want `document.getElementById("pageCombatAlien")` not `PageCombatAlien`